# How to find a "div" with attribute "data-status" and add an event to them?

Tags: html, jquery

I have a website which contains many `div`s. Some of them have an attribute `data-status`.

Example:

```
<div data-status="read">+-*</div>
<div data-status="unread">123</div>
<div data-status="sticked">xyz</div>
```

I want to add an `onClick` event to them. How can I identify these `div`s in Jquery?

These `div`s are not siblings! They are at different knots.

I found this example

```
$("input[value='Hot Fuzz']")
```

on [api.jquery.com](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), but with it I can find attributes with a value equal to my search only. But in my case, I want to find an attribute with ***any*** values. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple as the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) you already used `"[]"` - just, without the value part:

```js
$("[data-status]").on("click", function() {
  console.log(this.textContent)
});
```

```html
<div data-status="read">+-*</div>
<div data-status="unread">123</div>
<div data-status="sticked">xyz</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The same selector can be used in CSS too - if you'll ever need it:

```css
[data-status] {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div data-status="read">+-*</div>
<div data-status="unread">123</div>
<div data-status="sticked">xyz</div>
```